# How to keep ffmpeg alive? it keep exiting

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following setup:
1. I have Raspberry PI with camera module streaming video to IP using RPI Cam Control.
2. On my main PC I can view that feed and it works great. No problem there.
3. I am attempting to resend that feed in to /dev/video0 with ffmpeg, which sort of works. But it only works once.

The problem is ffmpeg just exits after sending one frame to /dev/video0 without any errors. I am previewing it with ffplay /dev/video0. It updates only when I run my ffmpeg command again and then ffmpeg just exits again.

I probably have some stupid mistake with ffmpeg command which I can't pinpoint:

```
ffmpeg -i http/192.168.1.201/html/cam_pic.php -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I was missing "loop" attribute which keeps it alive.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i http/192.168.1.201/html/cam_pic.php -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```